# Error in gcm push notification with php

Tags: php, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When I'm using gcm push notification,

```
Field"data"mustbeaJSONarray: {
    "details": [
        {
            "regid": "APA91bH8zxTxfoSLWhE21IbTR9a10cvIcm17-zsPY_0OAy3JhO_8gTwMwwAUd_4vZiLu5UF4A1m8R3TEIffDaChVR0y2us9iebngkaWlOM34ix4PUeOgIoM9aGOcxLLECAGjKNSwupTY0p2O0BeXjSCp8RYFaD-xzg",
            "status": "true",
            "post_userid": "34",
            "post_id": "7",
            "postuser_name": "dev",
            "message": "gggggg"
        }]}
```

and that give me error: **"Field data must be a JSON array"**

please guide me

My code :

```
$fields = array('data'=> $message); 
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY, 'Content-Type: application/json' ); 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'; );     
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); 
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) ); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close( $ch ); 
echo $result;
```

Comment: please show the code used to send the message to GCM.

Comment: $fields = array('data'=> $messsssagedddd);
            
    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,  'Content-Type: application/json'  );
      
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
 echo $result;

Comment: my code is:$fields = array('data'=> $message);
            
 $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,  'Content-Type: application/json'  );
      
    $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
     echo $result;

Answer (score 1):

Well, your JSON doesn't look like it's supposed to look.
It should be something like that :

```
{
  "data": {
        "status": "true",
        "post_userid": "34",
        "post_id": "7",
        "postuser_name": "dev",
        "message": "gggggg"
  },
  "registration_ids":["APA91bH8zxTxfoSLWhE21IbTR9a10cvIcm17-zsPY_0OAy3JhO_8gTwMwwAUd_4vZiLu5UF4A1m8R3TEIffDaChVR0y2us9iebngkaWlOM34ix4PUeOgIoM9aGOcxLLECAGjKNSwupTY0p2O0BeXjSCp8RYFaD-xzg"]
}
```

Comment: $fields = array('registration_ids'=>$msgd,array('data'=> $message));"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array

Comment: @DevangADD Then make it a JSON array. I don't know PHP but perhaps something like `$fields = array('registration_ids'=>array($msgd),array('data'=> $message));` would work.

Comment: whe i user this code:                                                                            $fields = array('registration_ids'=>$msgd,array('data'=> $message));                      it will show this error   "    "registration_ids"    field is not a JSON array"

Comment: @DevangADD What does `$msgd` contain?

Comment: it is regestration_id varialbble

Comment: Is their any problem in 'gcm push notification' form google side?